# Unable to add firebase data to list in android studio

Tags: java, android, arrays, firebase

I am making a quiz app where i will add questions in firebase database and it will show in my app in text view, but i am getting error :-  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

i have decleared a variable index;

this is my code;

```
enter code here
package com.example.quizz;

import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.Collections;

public class Main_Area extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseReference databaseReference;

 ArrayList<Modelclass> questionList;
 Modelclass modelclass;
 int index = 0;

 TextView textView;
 Button button2, button3, button4, button5,nxt_btn;


@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    setContentView(R.layout.main_area);

    textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
    button2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
    button4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
    button5 = findViewById(R.id.button5);
    nxt_btn = findViewById(R.id.button6);



    questionList = new ArrayList<>();

    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Question");

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot: snapshot.getChildren()){
                Modelclass modelclass = dataSnapshot.getValue(Modelclass.class);
                questionList.add(modelclass);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });

    // questionList.add(new Modelclass("what is capital of india ", " india", "virat","delhi","mumbai","delhi"));
    //questionList.add(new Modelclass("what is capital of us ", " india", "virat","delhi","WD","WD"));
  //  questionList.add(new Modelclass("what is capital of AUSTRALIA ", "canbra", "virat","delhi","mumbai","canbra"));
   // questionList.add(new Modelclass("what is capital of uk ", " india", "london","delhi","mumbai","london"));
  //  questionList.add(new Modelclass("what is capital of canada ", "montreal", "london","delhi","mumbai","montreal"));


    Collections.shuffle(questionList);
    modelclass = questionList.get(index);

    setALLdata();


    button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (questionList.get(index).getAnswer().equals(button2.getText().toString())){
                button2.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#59c639")));


            } else{
                button2.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")));

            }
            button2.setEnabled(false);
            button3.setEnabled(false);
            button4.setEnabled(false);
            button5.setEnabled(false);
        }

    });


    button3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (questionList.get(index).getAnswer().equals(button3.getText().toString())){
                button3.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#59c639")));


            } else{
                button3.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")));

            }
            button2.setEnabled(false);
            button3.setEnabled(false);
            button4.setEnabled(false);
            button5.setEnabled(false);
        }

    });


    button4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (questionList.get(index).getAnswer().equals(button4.getText().toString())){
                button4.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#59c639")));


            } else{
                button4.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")));

            }
            button2.setEnabled(false);
            button3.setEnabled(false);
            button4.setEnabled(false);
            button5.setEnabled(false);
        }

    });


    button5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (questionList.get(index).getAnswer().equals(button5.getText().toString())){
                button5.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#59c639")));


            } else{
                button5.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FF0000")));

            }
            button2.setEnabled(false);
            button3.setEnabled(false);
            button4.setEnabled(false);
            button5.setEnabled(false);
        }

    });

    nxt_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            index++;
           modelclass= questionList.get(index);
           setALLdata();
            button2.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#81358E")));
            button3.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#81358E")));
            button4.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#81358E")));
            button5.setBackgroundTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#81358E")));
            button2.setEnabled(true);
            button3.setEnabled(true);
            button4.setEnabled(true);
            button5.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
}

private void setALLdata() {
    textView.setText(modelclass.getQuestion());
    button2.setText(modelclass.getOption1());
    button3.setText(modelclass.getOption2());
    button4.setText(modelclass.getOption3());
    button5.setText(modelclass.getOption4());



 }
}
```

in this above code, the the that i have added in firebase will add in the list questionList and then from there it will display in my play, but the problem is that index is 0 which means the questions are not able to add in the list, but i have written all the code correct and not able to find any problem.

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: modelclass = questionList.get(index);   at this line i am getting error, please help

Comment: There is no way you can return the `questionList` as a result of a method. Firebase API is asynchronous. So please check the duplicate to see how can you solve this using a callback. You might also be interested in reading this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-firebase-realtime-database-using-get-269ef3e179c5).